# Backbone: Why assign `$('#footer')` to `el`?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I found the following statements:

[`el: '#footer'`](https://addyosmani.com/backbone-fundamentals/#getting-set-up)

[`var todosView = new TodosView({el: $('#footer')});`](https://addyosmani.com/backbone-fundamentals/#getting-set-up)

**Why assign `$('#footer')` to `el`? This is what really confused me. I read the post here, [What is the difference between $el and el in Backbone.js views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646526/what-is-difference-between-el-and-el-in-backbone-js-view), still confused.**

Also, I read:
The `view.$el` property is equivalent to `$(view.el)` and `view.$(selector)` is equivalent to `$(view.el).find(selector)`. In our TodoView example’s render method, we see `this.$el` used to set the HTML of the element and `this.$()` used to find subelements of class ‘edit’.

But, someone said
[If you call `$(this.el)`, your just keep executing the jquery selector to get the same jquery object. '$el' is the cached version of `$(this.el)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013531/backbone-this-el-vs-this-el)

What is "cached version"?

Comment: you can read about this in this post [What is difference between $el and el in Backbone.js view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646526/what-is-difference-between-el-and-el-in-backbone-js-view)

Comment: @V.S.V I read the post, but still confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## What is the difference between `$el` and `el`?

### The [`el` view property](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el)

> `this.el` can be resolved from a DOM selector string or an Element;
>   otherwise it will be created from the view's `tagName`, `className`, `id`
>   and `attributes` properties. If none are set, `this.el` is an empty `div`,
>   which is often just fine.

It is a DOM element object reference. **Do not set `el` directly**, use the [`view.setElement` method](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) instead if you want to change it.

### The [`$el` property](http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el)

> A cached jQuery object for the view's element. A handy reference
>   instead of re-wrapping the DOM element all the time.

I like how user [**mu is too short** puts it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646526/what-is-difference-between-el-and-el-in-backbone-js-view#comment23956136_16646526):

> ```
> this.$el = $(this.el);
> ```

Also **do not set `$el` directly,** use the [`view.setElement` method](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement).

### The `el` option

> An `el` reference may also be passed in to the view's constructor.

```
new Backbone.View({ el: '#element' });
new Backbone.View({ el: $('#element') }); // unecessary
```

It overrides the `el` property, which is then used for the `$el` property.

If a selector string is passed, it is replaced with the DOM element it represents.

## Why assign `$('#footer')` to el?

`this.el` can be a jQuery object. You can see that Backbone make sure `el` is a DOM element and `$el` is a jQuery object of it in the [`_setElement` function](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/8ec88604732944f197b352a6be22c8216ea9d3a1/backbone.js#L1285):

> ```
> _setElement: function(el) {
>   this.$el = el instanceof Backbone.$ ? el : Backbone.$(el);
>   this.el = this.$el[0];
> },
> ```

This shows why `this.$el` is equivalent to `$(this.el)`.

## But what is [`Backbone.$`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/8ec88604732944f197b352a6be22c8216ea9d3a1/backbone.js#L51)?

Backbone keeps a reference to whatever is `$`.

> For Backbone’s purposes, jQuery, Zepto, Ender, or My Library (kidding)
>   owns the `$` variable.

In our case, `$` is jQuery, so `Backbone.$` is just jQuery, but Backbone dependencies are flexible:

> Backbone's only hard dependency is [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) ( >= 1.8.3). For
>   RESTful persistence and DOM manipulation with [Backbone.View](http://backbonejs.org/#View), include
>   [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) ( >= 1.11.0), and [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) for older Internet Explorer support.
>   *(Mimics of the Underscore and jQuery APIs, such as [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) and [Zepto](http://zeptojs.com/),
>   will also tend to work, with varying degrees of compatibility.)*

## `this.$(selector)` is equivalent to `$(view.el).find(selector)`

In fact, **it's a little more efficient**, the [`$` view function](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/8ec88604732944f197b352a6be22c8216ea9d3a1/backbone.js#L1241) is just:

> ```
> $: function(selector) {
>   return this.$el.find(selector);
> },
> ```

## What is a cached jQuery object?

In this case, it only means that a jQuery object is kept inside a variable, which is reused inside the view. It avoids the costly operation of finding the element with `$(selector)` each time.

You can (and should) use this little optimization whenever possible, like inside the `render` function:

```
render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(/* ...snip... */));
    // this is caching a jQuery object
    this.$myCachedObject = this.$('.selector');
},

onExampleEvent: function(e) {
    // avoids $('.selector') here and on any sub-sequent example events.
    this.$myCachedObject.toggleClass('example');
}
```

*Prefixing the jQuery cached object variable with `$` is just a standard, not a requirement.*

---

Backbone's source code is less than 2000 lines, it's well-documented and easy to read. I highly encourage everyone to dive into it to easily understand the underlying logic.

They also offer an [**annotated source page**](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html) which is even easier to read.

## Additional reading

- Start here: [Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#)
- [Introduction to Backbone](http://www.clock.co.uk/blog/an-introduction-to-backbonejs)
- [Backbone patterns](http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/)
- [Best practices with Backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535649/what-are-your-best-practices-for-backbone-js-projects)

Comment: Thanks. very clear answer. But could you explain Backbone.$?

Comment: @BAE I totally can!

Comment: Thanks. I am willing to read the Backbone source codes, but do you know any good posts which can help me understand the source codes?

Comment: @BAE I think I'm done