# Where is the Backbone error coming from?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So, I am creating a basic view using Backbone, and when I go to run it, I get this TypeError:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Right-hand side of instanceof is not an object
```

The error is referencing multiple points inside the `backbone.min.js` file and line 18 in my program. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<HTML>
   <HEAD>
     <META CHARSET="UTF-8" />
     <TITLE>First View</TITLE>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.0.0/backbone-min.js"></script>
     <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">
         var PokeView = Backbone.View.extend({
             render: function() {
                 this.$el.html("Simisage");

                 return this;
             }
         });

         var myPokeView = new PokeView({ el: "#paragraph" });

         console.log(myPokeView instanceof Object);
         myPokeView.render();
     </SCRIPT>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY>
     <p id="paragraph"></p>
 </BODY>
```

I have been looking all over the internet and some people have encountered the same error, but it isn't related to Backbone. Is the solution for Backbone the same as the others? How can I fix this?

Comment: Someone did something like `Object = null`.

Comment: Oh really? Was it in the `backbone.min.js` file?

Comment: No idea, but looking at the above code that's the only thing that can cause that error.

Comment: It probably was. Is there a workaround for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use the [latest version of Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) which at the moment is 1.3.3.
2. Use the **non-minified** version of any lib *while in development.* There's even a big **Development Version** button to download the Backbone source file.
3. Read the dependencies list carefully, which for [version 1.0.0 of Backbone](https://cdn.rawgit.com/jashkenas/backbone/1.0.0/index.html) is:

   > Backbone's only hard dependency is [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) ( >= 1.4.3). For RESTful persistence, history support via Backbone.Router and DOM manipulation with Backbone.View, include [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js), and either [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) ( >= 1.7.0) or [Zepto](http://zeptojs.com/).

   And for [version 1.3.3](https://cdn.rawgit.com/jashkenas/backbone/1.3.3/index.html):

   > Backbone's only hard dependency is [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) ( >= 1.8.3). For RESTful persistence and DOM manipulation with [Backbone.View](https://cdn.rawgit.com/jashkenas/backbone/1.3.3/index.html#View), include [**jQuery**](https://jquery.com/) ( >= 1.11.0), and [**json2.js**](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) for older Internet Explorer support. *(Mimics of the Underscore and jQuery APIs, such as [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) and [Zepto](http://zeptojs.com/), will also tend to work, with varying degrees of compatibility.)*

So, in the code you shared, it looks like jQuery is missing. Just include it before the other libs and you should be ready to use Backbone.

Also, note that you're using the [`el` option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40321584/1218980) of the view with `#paragraph` element which doesn't exist yet in the document when executing that script snippet. To fix this, place the script tag at the bottom of the body.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>First View</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="paragraph"></p>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone.js"></script>
    <script>
        var PokeView = Backbone.View.extend({
            render: function() {
                this.$el.html("Simisage");
                return this;
            }
        });

        var myPokeView = new PokeView({ el: "#paragraph" });

        console.log(myPokeView instanceof Object);
        myPokeView.render();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I didn't need the use of the latest version. But it finally works; thanks!