# this.model.on change event not firing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-model

The "change" event is not firing in the following code.

```
var PageView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("body"),
    initialize: function(){
        this.model.on("change:loading", this.loader, this);
    },
    loader: function(){
        if(this.model.get("loading")){
            this.$el.find('.loader').fadeIn(700);
        }
        else 
            this.$el.find('.loader').fadeOut(700);
    },
});

var PageModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        loading: null,
    },
    initialize: function(){
        this.set({loading:false});
    },
});

$(function(){
    var pageModel = new PageModel({});
    var pageView = new PageView({model: pageModel});
})
```

It works if I'm adding this in the model's `initialize` function:

```
 setTimeout(function() {
     this.set({'loading': 'false'});
 }, 0);
```

I can leave it this way, but this is a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The situation explained

Here's the order the code runs:

1. the model is created,
2. model's `initialize` function is called, setting the `loading` attribute to `false`,
3. then the model is passed to the view,
4. then a listener is registered for the `"change:loading"`

The event handler is never called because the event never occurs after it was registered.

## Quick fix

First remove the set from the model.

```
var PageModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        loading: null
    }
});
```

Then, after creating the view, set the `loading` attribute.

```
var pageModel = new PageModel();
var pageView = new PageView({ model: pageModel });

pageModel.set('loading', false); // now the event should trigger
```

Since the listener is now registered before the model's `loading` attribute is changed, the event handler will be called.

## Optimized solution

Use Backbone's best practices:

- [Favor `.listenTo` over `.on`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16823746/1218980) to avoid memory leaks
- [Cache jQuery objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40321584/1218980)
- [Try to avoid setting the `el` property on the view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40321584/1218980)

**A view is an atomic component that should only care about itself and its sub-views.**

While in your case, it wouldn't matter much that you use the `el` property on the view, it still goes beyond the responsibilities of the view. Let the calling code deal with passing the element to use for this view.

```
var PageView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.model = new PageModel();
        this.$loader = this.$('.loader');
        this.listenTo(this.model, "change:loading", this.loader);
    },
    loader: function() {
        this.$loader[this.model.get("loading")? 'fadeIn': 'fadeOut'](700);
    },
    render: function() {
        this.loader();
        return this;
    }
});
```

Put the defaults where they belong.

```
var PageModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        loading: false
    }
});
```

Here we choose the `body` as the element to use for the view, using the `el` option, and then call `render` when ready.

```
$(function() {
    var pageView = new PageView({ el: 'body' }).render();
});
```

The event won't be triggered by the listener right away, instead, we use the `render` function to put the view in its default state. Then, any subsequent changes of the `loading` attribute will trigger the callback.

---

I have listed the [most useful answers I've written about Backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1218980/emile-bergeron?tab=profile) on my profile page. You should take a look, it goes from the beginning to advanced and even provides some clever Backbone components that solves common problems (like detecting a click *outside* a view).

Comment: Hey. I went to sleep yesterday and understood what was a problem. But you gave me couple things to think about : listento (trying to get why its better). 
And you wrote about el property, trying to avoid it, but you still passing it to a view. Why?
This is only the part of my view and model. I will use el a lot. Shoud i still init each el.child im going to use? Or use el with find() method?
Will render be triggered with delay?? If so, why?  Because of sequence? 
Thanks again for your full answer. Will check your page.

Comment: @aleXela `listenTo` is the newer and better way to bind events in Backbone, related to memory leaks with previous `.on`/`.bind`. About `el`, I advise against hardcoding the property in the view and letting the calling code deals with that. When using the `el` property/option directly, it's retrieved with a document wide jQuery selector. This could cause unwanted side-effects and performance problems.