# _.bindAll isn't working while rendering a Backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to understand the backbone `bindAll` function in addition to handling its contexts. In this case, the following implementation doesn't work.

1. Create a view to insert data from a list.
2. `_.bindAll (this, 'render');` Could you see the context of this in the function do? `$(this.el)` is `undefined`. Shouldn't it work using `_bindAll`?
3. The following does not append in the `ol` list

   ```
   $(this.el).append('idCurso->', cursoModelo.get('idCurso'),' titulo-> ', cursoModelo.get('titulo'));
   $(this.el).append('hola caracola');`.
   ```

**HTML**

```
<ol id="ListaLibros"/>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

**JS**

```
// create a view to print the model data in the html
var ListaLibrosView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#ListaLibros',
  initialize: function() {
    this.collection = cursoCollection;

    _.bindAll(this, 'render');

    this.render();
  },
  render: function() {
    console.log("funcion render");
    var listaLibrosLi = '';

    this.collection.each(function(cursoModelo) {
      $(this.el).append('idCurso->', cursoModelo.get('idCurso'), ' titulo-> ', cursoModelo.get('titulo'));
      $(this.el).append('hola caracola');
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Please format the code properly before posting...

Comment: Don't say `$(this.el)` when you can say `this.$el`. Backbone caches the jQuery-wrapped `el` in [`$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el) so you should use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're  not using using `this.el` directly inside `render`, but inside a `_.each()` callback, which is another function with different context. You need to make sure it has the same context as well, you can simply achieve it like `_.each(function(){}, this)` since it accepts the context as second argument.

Or if you're using ES6 you can use an arrow function as callback which does not create a new context like `_.each(i => {})`

Answer (score 2):

[TJ's right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483690/1218980), though you're using [`this.collection.each`, it's just a proxy](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) to [Underscore's `_.each`](http://underscorejs.org/#each).

Also, [`this.$el = $(this.el)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40321584/1218980). You should use `this.$el` directly.

Note that [`_.bindAll` is an Underscore's function](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll) and it is unrelated to Backbone. Since the problem comes from the nested each callback context, once fixed, you won't need `_.bindAll` at all.

In fact, I never needed `_.bindAll` and when seen in tutorials, most of the time, it's because it's outdated or wrongly used.