# Template tags not working Underscore/Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am using Backbone and Underscore attempting to display a list of posts. I have created two views, one to act as the container for the posts, and one for displaying the posts itself. I attempted to use the template tags for Underscore, but I am running into a strange issue. The tags do not seem to work.

I have loaded my libraries in order, at the top of my html btw.

Any advice as to what I am doing wrong?

[image: Issue]

Here are my views...

```
var ListContainerView = SOCIView.extend({
  el: $(".display_body")
  template: _.template($('#ListContainerView').html()),

  initialize: function () {
      _.bindAll(this, "render", "addAll");
      this.collection.bind("reset", this.render);
  },

  render: function(){
      $(this.el).html(this.template());
      this.addAll();
  },

  addAll: function () {
      this.collection.each(this.addOne);
  },

  addOne: function (model) {
      view = new ListItemView({ model: model });
      $("ul", this.el).append(view.render());
  }

});




var ListItemView = SOCIView.extend({ 
  tagName: "li",
  template: _.template($("#ListItemView").html()),

  initialize: function () {
      _.bindAll(this, 'render');
  },

  render: function () {
      return $(this.el).append(this.template(this.model.toJSON())) ;
  }

});
```

Also my data if needed...

```
[
  {
    "id":"1",
    "schedule":"2020-0417 17:00:00",
    "utc_offset":"420",
    "project_id":"1",
    "network":"facebook",
    "network_name":"TestFacebookPage",
    "network_thumb":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17634406_1854330461448271_6787736791983791423_n.jpg?oh=e4c3a3573c0fc59359422cfd66a3865a&oe=598721E7","message":"Test Post 1 (just text, approved)",
    "data":[],
    "customer_approved":"1",
    "manager_approved":"1",
    "rejection_message":"",
    "created_at":"2020-0413 17:41:03",
    "created_by":"admin",
    "created_by_id":"1",
    "created_by_name":"John Admin"
},

{
    "id":"2",
    "schedule":"2020-0419 19:00:00",
    "project_id":"1",
    "network":"facebook",
    "network_name":"TestFacebookPage",
    "network_thumb":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17634406_1854330461448271_6787736791983791423_n.jpg?oh=e4c3a3573c0fc59359422cfd66a3865a&oe=598721E7",
    "message":"Test Post 2 (text with image, approved)  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
    "data":{"pictures":["https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C9T6n0UUwAAOBaU.jpg"],"image_added":"true","picture":"https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C9T6n0UUwAAOBaU.jpg","type":"photo"},
    "customer_approved":"1",
    "manager_approved":"1",
    "rejection_message":"",
    "rejection_message_manager":"",
    "created_at":"2020-0413 17:42:34",
    "created_by":"admin",
    "created_by_id":"1",
    "created_by_name":"John Admin"
},

{
    "id":"3",
    "schedule":"2020-0421 22:00:00",
    "network":"facebook","network_name":
    "TestFacebookPage","network_thumb":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17634406_1854330461448271_6787736791983791423_n.jpg?oh=e4c3a3573c0fc59359422cfd66a3865a&oe=598721E7",
    "message":"Test Post 3 (link, approved) http://www.adultswim.com/videos/rick-and-morty/",
    "data":{"image_added":"true","pictures":["http://i.cdn.turner.com/adultswim/big/img/2015/07/17/Rick%26MortyS02_fbsearchTn.jpg"],"picture":"http://i.cdn.turner.com/adultswim/big/img/2015/07/17/Rick%26MortyS02_fbsearchTn.jpg","link":"http://www.adultswim.com/videos/rick-and-morty/","name":"Watch Rick and Morty on Adult Swim","caption":"www.adultswim.com","description":"Every episode of Rick and Morty is now on AdultSwim.com for free. Rick is a mad scientist who drags his grandson, Morty, on crazy sci-fi adventures. Their escapades often have potentially harmful consequences for their family and the rest of the world. Join Rick and Morty on AdultSwim.com as they trek through alternate dimensions, explore alien planets, and terrorize Jerry, Beth, and Summer.","domain":"www.adultswim.com","type":"link"},
    "customer_approved":"1",
    "manager_approved":"1",
    "rejection_message":"",
    "created_at":"2020-0413 17:43:29",
    "created_by":"admin",
    "created_by_id":"1",
    "created_by_name":"John Admin"
},

{
    "id":"4",
    "schedule":"2020-0424 17:00:00",
    "network":"facebook",
    "network_name":"TestFacebookPage",
    "network_thumb":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17634406_1854330461448271_6787736791983791423_n.jpg?oh=e4c3a3573c0fc59359422cfd66a3865a&oe=598721E7",
    "message":"Test Post 4 (text, pending)",
    "data":[],
    "customer_approved":"0",
    "manager_approved":"1",
    "rejection_message":"",
    "created_at":"2020-0413 17:43:48",
    "created_by":"admin",
    "created_by_id":"1",
    "created_by_name":"John Admin"
},

{
    "id":"5",
    "schedule":"2020-0426 19:00:00",
    "network":"facebook",
    "network_name":"TestFacebookPage",
    "network_thumb":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17634406_1854330461448271_6787736791983791423_n.jpg?oh=e4c3a3573c0fc59359422cfd66a3865a&oe=598721E7",
    "message":"Test Post 5 (picture, pending)",
    "data":[],
    "customer_approved":"0",
    "manager_approved":"1",
    "rejection_message":"",
    "created_at":"2020-0413 17:44:03",
    "created_by":"admin",
    "created_by_id":"1",
    "created_by_name":"John Admin"
},

{
    "id":"6",
    "schedule":"2020-0428 21:00:00",
    "network":"facebook",
    "network_name":"TestFacebookPage",
    "network_thumb":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17634406_1854330461448271_6787736791983791423_n.jpg?oh=e4c3a3573c0fc59359422cfd66a3865a&oe=598721E7",
    "message":"Test Post 6 (link, pending) https://www.reddit.com/",
    "data":{
        "image_added":"true",
        "pictures":["https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/2Hwaff37fC4f37j-3orrbjVAOVBChqbdm_dXeIhjlNw.jpg"],
        "picture":"https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/2Hwaff37fC4f37j-3orrbjVAOVBChqbdm_dXeIhjlNw.jpg",
        "link":"https://www.reddit.com/",
        "name":"reddit: the front page of the internet",
        "caption":"www.reddit.com",
        "description":"reddit: the front page of the internet",
        "domain":"www.reddit.com",
        "type":"link"
        },
    "customer_approved":"0",
    "manager_approved":"1",
    "rejection_message":"",
    "created_at":"2020-0413 17:44:19",
    "created_by":"admin",
    "created_by_id":"1",
    "created_by_name":"John Admin"
  }
]
```

Comment: There's a syntax error in the following: `$(".display_body": _.template($('#ListContainerView').html())`

Comment: `_.bindAll` is useless, you don't have to use it since it's already an object where the context is passed correctly by default. You have problems with the context because you're using [`bind`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on) without the context param.

Comment: [`$(this.el)` is a redundant version of the already available `this.$el`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40321584/1218980)

Comment: [Favor `listenTo` over `bind`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823746/backbone-js-listento-vs-on)

Comment: Excellent, thank you. However, could you point out the syntax error, I can't seem to locate where I went wrong.

Comment: Use `var` (or `let`/`const` for ES6) in front of new variable to avoid creating globals.

Comment: The syntax error is that you're placing a colon `:` inside a jQuery core function call. You probably want a comma `,` instead like this: `$(".display_body", _.template($('#ListContainerView').html())`

Comment: Don't forget the context with the [`each` function](http://underscorejs.org/#each): `this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);`

Comment: You are incredibly helpful, can't thank you enough. Started using Backbone for the first time two days ago so I'll take all of your advice to heart!

Comment: Though I don't get what you're trying to do with: `$(".display_body", _.template($('#ListContainerView').html())`

Comment: That is actually an error of mine, I was looking at the wrong spot. It should be  el: $(".takehome_body"),
 template: _.template($('#ListContainerView').html()),

Comment: Makes more sense! ;)

Comment: Would that fix my strange <%= %> issue? Every tutorial I've watched do not have those tags highlighted like it's an error like mine.

Comment: It will certainly help that you're context, template and element are configured correctly (no syntax error). It's normal that the underscore template tags `<% %>` appears as en error in most editors since they don't parse them as valid HTML tags nor valid JavaScript, but you can ignore these warnings.

Comment: You rock, thank you so much!

Comment: There is a list of answers on [my profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1218980/emile-bergeron?tab=profile) that deals with the most common problems you'll _probably_ encounter with Backbone.

Comment: `$("ul", this.el)` should be `this.$('ul')`, `$(this.el)` should be `this.$el`, `_.bindAll` is rarely needed these days, and `listenTo` is usually used instead of `bind`. Are you using an old tutorial perhaps?