# Events Wont work on Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I created a view and has the ff codes:

```
var app = app || {};

app.singleFlowerView = Backbone.View.extend({

  tagName: 'article',
  className: 'flowerListItem',
  // tells where to apply the views
  template: _.template( $("#flowerElement").html() ),
  // render
  render: function(){
    var flowerTemplate = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
    // el contains all the prop above and pass to backbone
    this.$el.html(flowerTemplate);
    return this;
  },

  events: {
    'mouseover': 'addBgColor',
    'mouseout': 'removeBgColor'
  },

  addBgColor: function(){
    this.$el.addBgColor('bgColorImage');
  },

  removeBgColor: function(){
    this.$el.removeBgColor('bgColorImage');
  }


});
```

When I run this to my HTML file I got the error addBgColor and removeBgColor is not a function. I have the CSS for this and all the models and views were set up.

Am I missing something here? Any idea why events doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

`this.$el.addBgColor` is the problem.

**The events are triggering** but you're calling `addBgColor` on the `$el` jQuery object, which is not a jQuery function, *like the error message is telling you.*

Check [what's the difference between `$el` and `el`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40321584/1218980).

Answer (score 0):

Tony, your events are cool and they are running they're just not doing anything.

`this.addBgColor()` will call your function in a view.

`this.$el` is referring to the html and there's no property called `addBgColor` assigned to `$el`.

You need to do something like change the class on your tag with the functions like so...

```
addBgColor: function(){
  this.$el.className = 'bgColorImage'
},

.bgColorImage {
  background-image: url('bgColorImage.jpg');
}
```